# can not find org.apache.myfaces.el.ValueBindingImpl class in myfaces-impl 2.1.6

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I am working on a jsf migration project. In the process of migration to jsf 2.0, I have replaced myfaces-api-1.1.5 and myfaces-impl1.1.5 with myfaces-impl(2.1.6). I got the following Exception.

```
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_22]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_22]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/myfaces/el/ValueBindingImpl
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_22]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389) [:1.6.0_22]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699) [:1.6.0_22]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657) [:1.6.0_22]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JsfManagedBeanProcessor.deploy(JsfManagedBeanProcessor.java:105)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.el.ValueBindingImpl from [Module "deployment.ASSET.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)
    ... 11 more
```

When I try to find out ValueBindingImpl in the jar files, I am not able to find org.apache.myfaces.el.ValueBindingImpl in the myfaces-impl(2.1.6).. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your code is using MyFaces 1.1 specific implementation classes instead of the JSF 1.1 API classes. For example,

```
ValueBinding binding = new ValueBindingImpl(...);
```

instead of

```
ValueBinding binding = application.createValueBinding(...);
```

You'd need to fix the code to remove MyFaces 1.1 specific implementation classes.

Note that `ValueBinding` is deprecated since JSF 1.2, if you can, replace by `ValueExpression`.

Comment: Hi BalusC, Thank you very much for the answer. I am working on fixing the code.